# How to disable socket.io in sails.js?

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I want to disable socket.io service, in this version of the development phase, I was not ready to use it, how should I configure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable it on the server side do this: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8911041

Then on the client side just remove the .js files that initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

For me `"sockets":false` in .sailsrc or sails/hooks.js is not working.

> sails v0.12.13, node v7.4.0.

I simply added this to config/sockets.js

```
beforeConnect: function(handshake, cb) {
  return cb('socket connections not allowed!', false);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable in the client-side.

1. Disable the loader of js/dependencies/sails.io.js
2. Add this HTML configuration script into your layout.

```html
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"
  autoConnect="false"
  environment="production"
  headers='{ "x-csrf-token": "<%= typeof _csrf === 'undefined' ? _csrf : '' %>" }'>
</script>
```

[Refered to the sails document here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client)
˚